# Dual criteria data validation in Excel

Tags: excel

Unlike the other questions posted with this topic, my criteria are not simple comparators. I want a dropdown list that includes all values in one named table excluding those values that meet another criteria. For instance a table includes employee names in one column and vacation dates in another column. I want the data validation to allow a list of employees who are not on vacation for a variable date drawn from another cell. The general method seems to be to create additional tables where the secondary criteria (in this case date) is the column header populated by items from the first list that satisfy some criteria. It seems impractical to create 365 tables named for each date and populated by rows of employees from the first table that have not requested that date off. Is there another way to accomplish this?
Sample Data:

```
| Employee| Vacation Dates  |        | work on 1/26/20 |
_____________________________        ___________________
| Bob     | 1/26/20, 1/27/20|        | <allow only     |
| Mike    | 2/20/20, 2/21/20|        | Mike or Cindy>  |
| Cindy   | 2/20/20, 1/28/20|
```

Comment: Some sample data and the expected result would be quite helpful here.

Comment: This sounds like a task for something with a proper database and query language to filter related data, not Excel.

Comment: Just use the custom validation with a formula. Then use AND or OR function to create the list. Something like AND(Query1,Query2). The custom validation, expects a boolean back

Comment: @BigBen, I have added sample data that I hope makes clear what I am asking.

Comment: @Monofuse ideally I would like to have a dropdown list, which a custom validation does not produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to transpose my thinking. Rather than a table for each date, I can have a vacation table for each employee. The validation formula has to be a custom validation rather than a list, so no drop down selection list is available, but it will work. Error message also cannot discriminate which criteria is being violated -- name not on employee list versus name from employee list who is on vacation. Would be great if validation worked like conditional formatting with different rules applied in sequence.

```
| Employee| Bob   | Mike    | Cindy |        | 1/26/20 |
____________________________________|        ___________
| Bob     |1/26/20| 2/20/20 |2/20/20|        |         |
| Mike    |1/27/20| 2/21/20 |1/28/20|        |         |
| Cindy   |
```

The validation formula for the "1/26/20" column (F in the scheme above) would be

```
=AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$4,F2)>0,COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(F2,$B$1:$D$1,0)+1)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,MATCH(G2,$B$1:$D$1,0)+1)),F1)<1)
```